# Iterate over SortedMap an delete entries

Tags: java, java-8

I hava a `SortedMap<Long, List<MyType>>` and I want to delete the `List<MyType>` and if the `List<MyType>` is empty than also I will delete the `Long` key.

IS there an elegant solution in Java 8 for that?

With this code I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
SortedMap<Long, List<MyType>> dates = ...

for (final Long key : this.getDates().keySet()) {
  for (final Iterator<MyType> iterator = this.getDates().get(key).iterator();
       iterator.hasNext();) {
    final MyType myType= iterator.next();
    if (myType.getMarker().intValue() == marker.intValue()) {
      iterator.remove();

      if (this.getDates().get(key).isEmpty()) {
        this.getDates().remove(key);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bit could be written:

```
for (List<MyType> list : dates.values()) {
  list.removeIf(myType -> myType.getMarker().intValue() == marker.intValue());
}
```

And the second bit could be written:

```
dates.values().removeIf(List::isEmpty);
```

That requires two passes but is, in my opinion, easier to understand (and the performance impact is probably marginal).

---

Alternative with an iterator:

```
for (Iterator<List<MyType>> it = dates.values().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  List<MyType> list = it.next();
  list.removeIf(myType -> myType.getMarker().intValue() == marker.intValue());
  if (list.isEmpty()) it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 collections now have a [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method you can leverage :

```
getDates().values().forEach(list -> list.removeIf(myType -> myType.getMarker().intValue() == marker.intValue()));
getDates().values().removeIf(List::isEmpty);
```

Comment: great solution - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate on the map entries. And for each entry, you could remove the matching value using a nested iterator. Last, you remove the entry is the value list is empty:

```
    Iterator<Entry<String, List<Integer>>> entryIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entryIterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry = entryIterator.next();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = entry.getValue().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer value = iterator.next();
            if (Objects.equal(value, marker)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        if (entry.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            entryIterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It’s interesting that you got away with replacing `MyType` with `Integer`. I was wondering whether these `intValue()` calls of the original code were really necessary, but eliding the `getMarker()` call as well never came to my mind. If the value object really is a `List<Integer>`, a simple `entry.getValue().removeAll(singleton(marker))` would be sufficient…

Comment: @Holger sure. I only want to show how to remove properly using iterators. II use Integer because it was simpler to write a basic program.